# Apache NiFi - Can it scale at the processor level?

Tags: etl, apache-nifi

Newbie Alert to Apache NiFi!

Curious to understand (and read relevant material) on the scalability aspects of Apache NiFi pipeline in a clustered set up.

Imagine there is a 2 node cluster Node 1 & Node 2.

A simple use case as an example:

1. Query a Database Table in batches of 100 (Lets say there are 10 batches).
2. For each batch, call a REST API (invoke Http).

If a pipeline is triggered on Node 1 in a cluster, Does this mean all the 10 batches are run only in Node 1?

Is there any work distribution "out-of-the-box" available in NiFi at every processor level? Along the lines of 5 batches are executed for the REST API calls per node.

Is the built-in queue of NiFi distributed in nature?

Or is the recommended way to scale at the processor level is to publish the output of the previous processors to a messaging middleware (like Kafka) and then make the subsequent NiFi processor to consume from it?

What's the recommended way to scale at every processor level in NiFi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

every queue has a load balancing strategy parameter with following options:

- `Do not load balance`: Do not load balance FlowFiles between nodes in the cluster. This is the default.
- `Partition by attribute`: Determines which node to send a given FlowFile to based on the value of a user-specified FlowFile Attribute.
- `Round robin`: FlowFiles will be distributed to nodes in the cluster in a round-robin fashion.
- `Single node`: All FlowFiles will be sent to a single node in the cluster.

Details in documentation:

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#Load_Balancing

Comment: Thanks for the response. That was useful. Can I know what are the underpinnings of NiFi queues? Do they use an existing message broker as part of the framework? Or does it use it's own distributed Queueing primitives?

Comment: own file based implementation because flowfiles could be large/massive